# Pandas - How can I replace NaN values from next row if values in different column are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, replace

My df looks like bellow

```
ID Name     SupervisorID    Date
1  John     NaN             2021-02
1  John     123             2021-03
2  Thomas   NaN             2021-02
2  Thomas   234             2021-03
3  Ann      NaN             2021-02
3  Ann      567             2021-03
4  Alice    NaN             2021-03
5  Mark     324             2021-03
```

I need to fill missing SupervisorID with previus ID from another month (I have only two dates: 2021-02 and 2021-03). So if SupervisorID is NaN and ID, Name columns are the same for ID and Name, it should fill SupervisorID with previus ID, so df should looks like below:

```
ID Name     SupervisorID    Date
1  John     123             2021-02
1  John     123             2021-03
2  Thomas   234             2021-02
2  Thomas   234             2021-03
3  Ann      564             2021-02
3  Ann      567             2021-03
4  Alice    NaN             2021-03
5  Mark     324             2021-03
```

I hope, that it is clear.

Best regards and thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is different months per combination `ID, Name` use [`GroupBy.bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.bfill.html):

```
df['SupervisorID'] = df.groupby(['ID','Name'])['SupervisorID'].bfill()
```

Comment: It works fine. I have to say that I did't know bfill(). that's new for me :) thanks!